# Eigenvalues of a symmetric positive definite matrix are all greater than $0$

Tags: linear-algebra

The eigenvalues of a symmetric positive definite matrix are all greater than zero. Prove this by considering the eigen-decomposition $A=QDQ^T$, with $Q$ orthogonal and $D$ diagonal. How exactly do I show this?

I'm not really sure how to approach this. I believe I should start by doing the following: $A=QDQ^T \implies Q^TA = DQ^T$ since $Q^{-1} = Q^T$. It follows then that $Q^TAQ =D$. The right side contains all the eigenvalues. If I could show that the left side becomes a diagonal with positive values, then I'd be done. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

Another inclination is to consider eigen-vectors of $A$, say $v_i$. Since $A$ is positive definite, $x^TAx>0$ for all $x\neq0$. So considering a normalized eigenvector $v_i$ and its associated eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, we have

$v_i^TQDQ^Tv_i>0$

But $Q^Tv_i = (v^Tv_i \hspace{1mm}\cdots\hspace{1mm}v^T_nv_i)^T = (0 \cdots0\hspace{1mm}1\hspace{1mm} 0\cdots0)^T$

and similarly,

$v_i^TQ = (v_i^Tv_1\hspace{2mm}\cdots\hspace{2mm}v_i^Tv_n) =  (0 \cdots0\hspace{1mm}1\hspace{1mm} 0\cdots0)$

Letting $D = diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_i,...\lambda_n)$, we get

$(0 \cdots0\hspace{1mm}1\hspace{1mm} 0\cdots0)diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_i,...\lambda_n)(0 \cdots0\hspace{1mm}1\hspace{1mm} 0\cdots0)^T = \lambda_i > 0$.

Thus, this holds for the set $B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ of all normalized eigenvectors of $A$. So, is this a valid proof using eigendecomposition? If so, how does this change if we do not consider normalized eigenvectors?

Comment: Observe that $A$ and $D$ have the same eigenvalues. Observe that $A$ induces a bilinear form $\langle u, v \rangle = u^t A v$ which is positive-definite by definition. After a change of basis this is the same as the bilinear form induced by $D$, $\langle u, v \rangle := u^t D v$. Using that $A$ is positive-definite, the bilinear form induced by $D$ is positive-definite. But this can only happen if the diagonal entries are all positive.

Answer (score 2):

An operator $A$ is positive-definite if, for every vector $v$, we have $\langle v, Av \rangle > 0$, where $\langle v, u \rangle = v^T u$ denotes the dot-product. If we have an eigenvector $Av = \lambda v$ of the positive-definite operator $A$, then $\langle v, Av \rangle = \lambda \langle v, v \rangle > 0$ and so $\lambda > 0$.

If the operator $A$ is also symmetric, then all of its eigenvalues are real, and hence all positive.

Comment: Yes, but this does not make use of the eigendecomposition.

Comment: @physicsmajor Why would you want to use the eigendecomposition? You can prove the statement directly from the definitions of eigenvalues and positive-definite, without resorting to eigendecompositions. All the decomposition $A = QDQ^T$ is telling you anyway is that there is some orthonormal basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ such that all the $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: I think the OP is asking why the *complex* eigenvalues of $A$ are all positive reals. Since positive definiteness is defined by $x^TAx>0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$, there is a gap in your argument: as $A$ can have a complex eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$, you cannot argue that $v^TAv>0$ because $v$ is not real.

Comment: @user1551: since symmetric matrices are all diagonalisable with real eigenvalues, the point is moot. But I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: That is part of the stated problem-- to use eigendecomposition.

Comment: "The eigenvalues of a symmetric positive definite matrix are all greater than zero. Prove this by considering the eigen-decomposition $A=QDQ^T$, with $Q$ orthogonal and $D$ diagonal."

Comment: I found that if I considered $v_i = c_i b_i$, where $v_i$ is an eigen vector, $b_i$ a normalized eigen vector, and $c_i$ a coefficient that may be complex, then all the $1$'s in my proof become $c_i$, and the resulting inequality becomes $c_i^2\lambda_i > 0$ which implies $ \lambda_i >0$.